# Issue with GLC-T on in a Nexus 7000 F2e line card

Tags: cisco, cisco-nx-os, cisco-nexus-7k

We are experiencing an issue with a GLC-T SFP in a F2e Line card on a Nexus 7000. No matter what is tried we can it will not go up/up. This connection will go from one Nex7k to another and is intended to be for vPC keep alive. We are running current code 6.2.2a. We also have a Sup2 in the switch. Other SFPs in teh line card work properly.

We have tried
- Different ports on the same line card on different port groups
- Connecting to other devices such as a laptop
- replacing cables
- Hard setting speed and duplex
- Tested the SFP in other devices. (that came out of a ASR1k)
- tested in both switchport and routed modes.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: I have had no trouble using GLC-T SFP's in N7K-F248XP-25 or N7K-M148GS-11L linecards. Are your SFPs Cisco branded or 3rd party? If my memory serves me right the instructor at the n7k-course said the nexus is a bit more particular about SPF's. He also said you should use the out of band management for VPC-keep alive. What does your sh int e x/y tranceiver details say?

Comment: may be you have faulty cable, glc-t will up only in 1000baseT mode(not 100baseT)

Comment: I've had trouble with GLC-T SFP's in certain IOS-XE devices before - realise this is NX-OS - in all cases SFP-GE-T SFP's have worked. It may be worth considering using one instead (they are a bit more expensive). Obvious question is have you raised a TAC case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a software issue if I recall correctly

Answer (score -1):

Set on the Interface
speed 1000
We had the issue on Nexus 5600 Switches and that did the trick.

Comment: The OP explicitly mentions hard setting different speed and duplex.

Comment: Sorry I don't get you what different speed would you set for a GLC-T. We have it operational on many ports and you don't need to set Duplex.